# Including External ID in CDC

Tags: platform-event, change-data-capture

We are implementing CDC to mirror record changes in Salesforce to our other platforms. When a change occurs to a record the `recordIds` are passed which contain the Salesforce IDS. However our external systems do not retain these ids, is it possible to include an external ID into our messages?

Comment: Guess what, this Winter 20 release heard your requirement, it has what you want.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_change_data_capture_enrichment.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's not.

The Change Data Capture CREATE and UNDELETE events include all field values already, so they're not the issue. The problem lies in the UPDATE and DELETE events. The former includes only the changed fields and the record Id, and the latter includes only the record Id. (This is documented in the [Change Data Capture Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_event_fields_body.htm)).

With regular DML, it's sometimes useful to fake an update by doing, e.g., `update new Account(Id = 'SOME_ID');` as a no-op. I thought perhaps we could do the same with CDC by doing a no-op update against records, setting an External Id field to itself to force it to be included in the change event. Unfortunately, CDC is cleverer than that. I tried it with both a `before update` and `after update` trigger

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    List<Account> updates = new List<Account>();
    if (!StaticHelper.running) {
        for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
            updates.add(
                new Account(
                    Id = a.Id,
                    External_Id__c = a.External_Id__c
                )
            );
        }
        StaticHelper.running = true;
        update updates;
        StaticHelper.running = false;
    }
}
```

But logs still show

> 15:17:37.0 (7401510)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|External Id: null

via a simple `AccountChangeEvent` trigger:

```
trigger AccountChangeEventTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert) {
    for (AccountChangeEvent e : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('External Id: ' + e.External_Id__c);
    }
}
```

CDC only includes the field in the change event if its value actually changed. To do this directly, I think you'd need to have an additional system in the mix maintaining a persistent store of Salesforce Id -> External Id. (Any creations or changes of External Ids *will* be transmitted through CDC).

### Side-Step Solution

Here's another possibility, whose applicability will depend on how much flexibility you have in your target system and whether or not you have a middleware solution sitting in front of it.

Define your External Id field in Salesforce to be one character longer than in your external system. Use that extra character as an auto-incrementing, wrapping counter, via a `before update` trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        a.External_Id__c = a.External_Id__c.left(a.External_Id__c.length() - 1) + ((Integer.valueOf(a.External_Id__c.right(1)) + 1) % 10);
    }
}
```

This *does* get the External Id + autoincrementing counter into the change events on any update:

> 15:27:44.0 (7999288)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|External Id: Test2
>
> 15:37:33.0 (7287164)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|External Id: Test3

The viability of such shenanigans depends, of course, on your having some way to configure your external system or middleware platform to truncate the External Id by one character so as to ignore this cyclical change.

There's a few other variant tricks that could conceivably work. For example, if your External Ids always include an alphabetic character, and your remote system is not case-sensitive, you could invert the capitalization of the External Id on each update.

Change events also [don't include formula fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_general_considerations.htm), so unfortunately there's no roundabout route there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the requirement is quite unique, I can come up with 2 solutions.

1) **Using CDC and Platform Events**: You write [Async Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/06/get-buildspiration-with-asynchronous-apex-triggers-in-summer-19.html) on Object, then you query the External ID for those records and Fire a custom Platform Event having the serialised data of that record with external id. The third party will subscribe to Platform Event instead of CDC event

2) **Ditch CDC and Use Platform Events** : Platform events give you more power than CDC, in the After event of your normal Sobject , just pass the New / Changed values as Platform Event's field. Now you have the control which fields you want to send and how you wanna send it.

I would personally prefer 2nd Option.

**WINTER 20 UPDATE** : Starting winter 20, you can now make certain fields always included in CDC event. This is default Out of the Box Functionality.

More Here: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_change_data_capture_enrichment.htm

Comment: I think (2) is the way to go. (1) can break if the records are deleted or mutated between the sync transaction and the invocation of the async trigger.

Comment: @DavidReed if deleted then can use ALL_ROWS for SOQL, if updated in between another event will fire as we are just using External ID, if External ID changes then it will part of initial CDC Event.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include unchanged field values in your change event messages for processing or replicating data, you can use [event enrichment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_enrich_intro.htm). This feature is supported for subscribers that use CometD, such as Streaming API clients or EMP Connector, or Pub/Sub API.